# put space between items in a row

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, react-native

Is there any way to style elements (from the `ratings` view) in such a way that there's automatically some space between them? I thought of printing text (white spaces) but that doesn't sound like an ideal solution. What else can I do?

```
 <View style={styles.introContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.name}>{firstName}</Text>
          <View style={styles.ratings}>
            <Icon name="user" size={moderateScale(20)} />
            <Icon name="star" size={moderateScale(13)} />
            <Text style={styles.rating}> {rating}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
```

[image: ss]

```
  ratings: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    //alignContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'baseline',
  },
  introContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingTop: 50,
    width: '100%',
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

add `margin` or `padding` to whatever element you want to give it more space

or you could apply a `width` to a few elements and use

```
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
```

so they are spaced equally

Comment: are you suggesting that I should apply width to the ```ratings``` view or to each icon separately? Applying it to ratings and then adding display, justify-content didn't work

Comment: really? that's weird it didn't work. did you set a big enough width? what happens if you apply width to `styles.ratings` of say 300px?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Sorry, there is no support for `grid` by default in React Native, so option 3 is discarded unless you want to use a third-party library like https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-responsive-grid

**Option 1:**

Give the star icon a right and left margin

**Option 2:**

Add `width` and `display: flex` to the `ratings` style and set the `justifyContent` to `space-between` or `space-around`

**Option 3:**

Use grid instead of flex and set a `grid-gap`

Comment: I tried option 2 but nothing changed. What width should I use? I tried with 100. For option 3, could you give an example of how to use grid? I am not using flex right not so I am not what to replace

Comment: I updated the answer, you need to add `display: flex` to the `ratings` view as well, and as for grid, I just found there is no support for it in RN right now, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the children of `View` component you can try to use:

```css
.ratings > * {
 // your css here
}
```

By using `>` you are targeting direct children of the `parent` selector ( in this case the `.ratings` class selector.

`*` means any kind of children element, although you should be more specific if you can (all children should be targeted by the same class or be the same html element)
[css child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator)

Comment: You can't use css selectors by default in React Native

Comment: Good catch I've missed the `react-native` tag